# Create FILE* from String

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using a library where they used paths to define input and output files where data gets read from/written to.

`App1` writes the input file, `App2` reads that input file and creates an output file. Then, `App1` reads the output and everyone is happy.

Now, we get the requirement that for the communication between `App1` and `App2`, no files shall be created anymore. Therefore, `App1` shall pass a buffer to `App2` (a simple `char*`) along with a pre-allocated output buffer where `App2` shall write the results to.

Unfortunately, throughout the library that is used in `App2`, a `FILE*` is used to read from/write to.

**So, here's the question:** can I achieve – it without rewriting the library used by App2 – (or with minor changes) that I can use the buffers passed from `App1` to `App2` for information exchange? IMHO this would require that I could create a `FILE*` from a buffer without having that `FILE*` on the disk.

I read that for .NET I could use the `System.IO.StringReader` class, but since I'm using plain C++ and no .NET, I cannot use that stuff.

---

*Extra Bonus:*
The caller (i.e. `App1`) is managed code (C# application), the callee (i.e. `App2`) is a plain C++ DLL (i.e. `App1` calls a function in that DLL).

---

*Edit:*
I'd favor answers where the data exchange could happen synchronously in a way that the caller passes buffers to the callee, the callee reads from the input buffer and writes to the output buffer, then the callee terminates and the caller could read the content of the buffers.

Comment: For the last part, just create a thread in the caller that deals with the callee.

Comment: @MSalters: hm. this would be the consequence. tried to avoid this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For IPC you can use pipes, it is easy to make `FILE*` from winapi `HANDLE` created for pipe.

This code will show how:

```
HANDLE read_hnd;
HANDLE write_hnd;
//make sa (SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)
if(!CreatePipe(&read_hnd, &write_hnd, &sa, NULL))
{
//error
}
int fd = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)read_hnd, _O_RDONLY|_O_TEXT);
FILE *pipe_read_file = _fdopen(fd, "rt");
```

For IPC you should use named pipes, but idea the same.

Comment: See edited question: is communication over pipes also possible between managed and unmanaged code?

Comment: @eckes See edited answer, you can create `FILE*` which really points to pipe.

Comment: I think, pipes are not the right measure. In order to get the efforts minimal, the data exchange should happen synchronously. But for pipes, there seem to be waiting points where one side waits for the other. Could you expand your answer by that case (i.e. is it possible for the caller to store a message for the callee in a named pipe)? See updated question for that.

Comment: Yes @eckes you can do what you want via named pipes:
1. Create named pipe and let `App1` writes to the pipe and `App2` reads to from pipe (the operation can be even asincroniously).
2. `App2` will create named pipe and write to it, and App1 will read from this file (seperate thread should be used for this operation in both apps)

Comment: You may need to be aware of the pipe's internal buffer size, though: if App1 attempts to write more than the buffer size to the pipe, the write will block until App2 reads from the pipe enough that there is space for App1 to write again. (If you do need to manage a large amount of data, one workaround might be to use an intermediate thread, C, where App1 writes via pipe to C, which stores the data in memory that you allocate and grow as needed, and then writes that to another pipe for App2 to read.)

Comment: @Mihran: if I open the pipe in `A` and write data to it before calling `B`, I get error 536 (ERROR_PIPE_LISTENING). Obviously this is because `B` is not already running and therefore `A` cannot write into the pipe, right? So either I do it async (WriteFileEx) or run a separate thread in `A` that acts as pipe server?

Comment: @eckes **solution 1**: Yes you can run fake pipe server in `A` to be able to write to pipe, and then open pipe handle in `B` as well. **solution 2**: open pipe in `A` and wait when `B` opens it too.